# discord.py: How to catch error when specific role was not found in command arguments?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a `addrole`-Command which allows you to add a specific role to a specific member and I want that the bot sends a message, if the bot doesn't find the member or the role. My command looks like that:

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx, choice = None, member: discord.Member = None, rolein: discord.Role = None):
    # some code
```

I know I can catch the error if the bot doesn't find the member like that:

```
@role.error
async def role_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        # ...
```

But how can I detect if a role wasn't found?

Comment: what two situations? When you get error? Which line of code gives error? We can't run it to see it. Show it in question (not in comment)

Comment: I edited to: "But I don't know how to do that at two situations (at the BadArgument-Error of member and of role)"

Comment: `error.message` should contain the name of the failing argument, can you use that directly?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Can you give me an example please?

Comment: `await ctx.send(error.message)`

Comment: okay, I'll test it out.

Comment: Mhh okay, the bot sends:
"Member "test" not found"
But how can I "customize" the message myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Context` has an attribute `args` which returns a list of all the successful arguments, up until the first unsuccessful one. You can use it to check how many arguments were successful:

```py
@role.error
async def role_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        if len(ctx.args) == 2:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, I couldn't find that user.")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, I couldn't find that role.")
```

The context object will always be the first element in that list, which is why if the first argument fails, then only the context object will exist in that list, hence giving it a length of 1. And the length of the list will be 3 if the user was found but the role wasn't.

It's important to note that it stops adding arguments to the list at the ***first*** incorrect argument it finds.
This means, in your case, that if the role was found but the user wasn't, then the length of the list will still only be 2.

---

**Reference:**

- [`Context.args`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.args)

*Edited the numbers used because I just realised you had another argument preceeding `member`.